# Convert json file to dataframe and remove whitespaces and newlines from value

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a json file a.json that has the following structure:

```
[
    { "name":"\n     John\n        ", "age":  "30  \n ","car":"   Bmw   \n   \n" },
    { "name":"\n     Joe\n        ", "age":  "20  \n ","car":"    mercedes   \n   \n" },
    { "name":"\n     Alex\n        ", "age":  "18  \n ","car":"      tesla   \n   \n" }
]
```

I want to strip off all the whitespaces and newlines for every value.
Here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_json('a.json')
df= df.replace(r'\n','',regex=True)
```

i removed the the newline but not the whitespaces even though that i write

```
df.columns=df.columns.str.replace(' ','')
df.columns=df.columns.str.strip()
df.columns=df.columns.str.lstrip()
```

**My output:**

```
                name  age                 car
0       John           30           Bmw
1        Joe           20      mercedes
2       Alex           18         tesla
```

How can i do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@chitown88](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7752296/chitown88)'s answer is probably faster, but if you want to do it using regex you can do it like that:

```
df.replace('(^\s+|\s+$)', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

**Output:**

```
   name  age       car
0  John   30       Bmw
1   Joe   20  mercedes
2  Alex   18     tesla
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas applymap function to iterate all value

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('a.json')
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
print(df)
```

Output :

```
   name  age       car
0  John   30       Bmw
1   Joe   20  mercedes
2  Alex   18     tesla
```

Answer (score 1):

An other quite similar but bit more compact way would be:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("a.json")

df_obj = df.select_dtypes(['object'])
df[df_obj.columns] = df_obj.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   name  age       car
0  John   30       Bmw
1   Joe   20  mercedes
2  Alex   18     tesla
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use list and dictionary comprehension to clean up the json itself:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    { "name":"\n     John\n        ", "age":  "30  \n ","car":"   Bmw   \n   \n" },
    { "name":"\n     Joe\n        ", "age":  "20  \n ","car":"    mercedes   \n   \n" },
    { "name":"\n     Alex\n        ", "age":  "18  \n ","car":"      tesla   \n   \n" }
]


data = [{k:v.strip() for k,v in each.items()} for each in data]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Or you could just iterate through each column:

```
data = [
    { "name":"\n     John\n        ", "age":  "30  \n ","car":"   Bmw   \n   \n" },
    { "name":"\n     Joe\n        ", "age":  "20  \n ","car":"    mercedes   \n   \n" },
    { "name":"\n     Alex\n        ", "age":  "18  \n ","car":"      tesla   \n   \n" }
]


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].str.strip()
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
   name age       car
0  John  30       Bmw
1   Joe  20  mercedes
2  Alex  18     tesla
```

Comment: I got this error `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`

Comment: that means there's something different in the dataset you have versus the one you provided here. are there nulls in the data. Is any of the data stored as int or floats?